# Debugging the AVR with GDB

Tags: linux, debugging, avr, avr-gcc

I've got a pcb with an Atmega88 and I only put the 6 pin header on the pcb for ICSP.  I have an AVR Dragon, and the 6 pin header there is for debugWIRE.

The problem I ran into is that my firmware guy is unable to finish the project and I need to do some debugging, but I only have a Linux machine.

I can program it with eclipse and with avrdude on the command line, but I have no clue where to begin with debugging.

I'm a hardware guy and only have a cursory exposure to embedded programming. I've seen a lot of posts regarding jtag and a few with debugWIRE, but they all start over my head.

My question is, what is a good resource to learn the basics for debugging a bare metal avr with Ubuntu Linux?

Comment: Is there a reason you couldn't use Atmel Studio 6 running in wine?  Just throwing it out there

Comment: I could I suppose.   I had assumed that there would be a big disconnect in the hardware layer to AVR Studio through the emulator layer.

Comment: Honestly there may be.  I'd give it a shot though just because thats probably the most straight forward way for you in that you don't have such a large learning curve.

Comment: I agree.  I do see a benefit in climbing learning curves, though and this is a pretty low pressure project to do so with.  Good suggestion nonetheless!

Comment: If it fails, try this out, looks promising: 
http://www.instructables.com/id/Debugging-AVR-code-in-Linux-with-simavr/

Comment: important definition is wrong icp->icsp